# How to improve NodeHandle build and execution errors

Tags: c++, nodehandle

Raspberry Pi 4, Lubuntu20.04, ROS1-noetic

Please help me because I am getting an error with **NodeHandle**

My program is below
(Some Japanese is mixed in)

The **publish node** will be as follows
https://github.com/rt-net/rt_usb_9axisimu_driver/tree/master

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;
double gravity = 10.1347;  // 重力加速度

void imuCallback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& imu_msg)
{
    // IMUデータからクォータニオンを取得
    tf::Quaternion orientation;
    tf::quaternionMsgToTF(imu_msg->orientation, orientation);

    // クォータニオンからオイラー角を取得
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    tf::Matrix3x3(orientation).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);

    // 自己位置を計算（ここでは単純化）
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double z = 0.0;

    // 自己位置情報をPublish
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose_msg;
    pose_msg.header = imu_msg->header;
    pose_msg.pose.position.x = x;
    pose_msg.pose.position.y = y;
    pose_msg.pose.position.z = z;

    // クォータニオンから姿勢情報をBroadcast
    static tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;
    tf::Transform transform;
    transform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(x, y, z));
    transform.setRotation(orientation);
    broadcaster.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, imu_msg->header.stamp, "imu_link", "base_link"));

    // 自己位置情報をPublish
    // 自己位置情報をPublish
    static ros::Publisher pose_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("estimated_pose", 10);
    pose_pub.publish(pose_msg);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "self_localization_node");
    ros::Subscriber imu_sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Imu>("/imu/data_raw", 10, imuCallback);

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error

```
[FATAL] [1698211644.979626372]: You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle
[ERROR] [1698211645.036590112]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [:0].  Retrying...
```

But when I put the **NodeHandle inside the main function**, I get the below error when building

```
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/rt_usb_9axisimu_driver/src/rt_usb_9axisimu_odo_sub.cpp: In function ‘void imuCallback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/rt_usb_9axisimu_driver/src/rt_usb_9axisimu_odo_sub.cpp:40:38: error: ‘nh’ was not declared in this scope
   40 |     static ros::Publisher pose_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("estimated_pose", 10);
      |                                      ^~
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/rt_usb_9axisimu_driver/src/rt_usb_9axisimu_odo_sub.cpp:40:77: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   40 |     static ros::Publisher pose_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("estimated_pose", 10);
      |                                                                             ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/imu_subscriber_odometory.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/imu_subscriber_odometory.dir/src/rt_usb_9axisimu_odo_sub.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1848: CMakeFiles/imu_subscriber_odometory.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Please help me

Comment: I was able to do it by adding a variable within the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

#### Problems

There are following issues with your code:

1. `NodeHandle` is initilized before `ros::init()` which is unacceptable.
2. `tf::TransformBroadcaster` is created inside a callback. Initilization should be done outside callback and callback must be used to repetitive tasks.
3. Similarly, `ros::Publisher` is created inside a callback which should be avoided.

#### Solution

Simply define a class to encapsulate all the functionalities. The `tf::TransformBroadcaster` and `ros::Publisher` can be initilized as class members.

#### Example

I have create a demo code as an example. Please see below:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>

class MyClass
{
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_rel;
    ros::Publisher pose_pub;
    ros::Subscriber string_sub;
    size_t counter;

public:
    MyClass();
    void stringCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg);
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    counter = 0;
    nh_rel = ros::NodeHandle("~");
    pose_pub = nh_rel.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("estimated_pose", 10);
    string_sub = nh_rel.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("/string/data_raw", 10, &MyClass::stringCallback, this);
}

void MyClass::stringCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg)
{
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Received message:" << msg->data << " counter is:" << counter);
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose_msg;
    pose_msg.pose.position.x = counter++;
    pose_msg.pose.position.y = counter++;
    pose_msg.pose.position.z = counter++;
    pose_pub.publish(pose_msg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
    MyClass my_class;
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

The `NodeHandle` is initilized after `ros::init` inside the class and then publishers, subscribers etc are created. Pay attention to how and where they are initilized. The callback is only publishing the data.

#### How to run

1. Start roscore by `$ roscore`
2. Publish dummy string `$ rostopic pub -r 10 /string/data_raw std_msgs/String hello`
3. Invoke above node:

   ```
   $ rosrun my_pkg my_node
   [ INFO] [1698214701.051547495]: Received message:hello counter is:0
   [ INFO] [1698214701.151819953]: Received message:hello counter is:3
   [ INFO] [1698214701.251777275]: Received message:hello counter is:6
   [ INFO] [1698214701.351677097]: Received message:hello counter is:9
   [ INFO] [1698214701.451825040]: Received message:hello counter is:12
   ```
4. Verify that the data is published:

   ```
   $ rostopic echo /my_node/estimated_pose
   header: 
     seq: 187
     stamp: 
       secs: 0
       nsecs:         0
     frame_id: ''
   pose: 
     position: 
       x: 561.0
       y: 562.0
       z: 563.0
     orientation: 
       x: 0.0
       y: 0.0
       z: 0.0
       w: 0.0
   ---
   ```

I hope you can modify the above code to meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
I'll try it right away tomorrow.

Comment: I appriciate your response. If this answer helped you to find the issue and the problem is resolved, please (1) upvote and (2) mark this answer as accepted. Please look at the top left corner of the answer.